# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-1-1-0.dll is missing after QGIS 2.14 installation

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

After I install QGIS version 2.14 ESSEN on Windows 7,error message shows,

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-[1-1-0.dll is
> missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this
> problem.

I have tried reinstalling the program inumerable number of times but it does not work.Whereas QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas version is working very well.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Which installer did you use for 2.14 and 2.18? And why do you want 2.14 if 2.18 works for you?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file . See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237866/installation-qgis-impossible#